# This listview lags even after using viewholder

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, android-viewholder

Following is the code for the customadapter file. I am using regex to manipulate the strings. It is a music player app and this code shows the song's name and it's artist's name but it lags while scrolling.

**customAdapter.java**

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> {
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView songName;
        TextView artistName;
        int position;
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public customAdapter(Activity context, List <String> songList) {
        super(context, 0, songList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String song = getItem(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.song, parent, false);
            holder.songName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_song_name);
            holder.artistName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_artist_name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        try {

            metaRetriver.setDataSource(song);

            try {
                String[] temps = song.split("/");
                String temp = temps[temps.length - 1];
                temp = temp.replaceAll("\\s*\\([^\\)]*\\)\\s*", "");
                temp = temp.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");
                holder.songName.setText(temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 4));
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                holder.songName.setText("Unknown");
            }

            try {
                String temp = metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
                temp = temp.replaceAll("\\s*\\([^\\)]*\\)\\s*", "");
                if(temp.equals(""))
                    holder.artistName.setText("Unknown");
                else
                    holder.artistName.setText(temp);
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                holder.artistName.setText("Unknown");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return convertView;
    }
   }
```

Please help!!

Comment: Is the lag in the emulator or actually on a phone? Emulators will run slower. - Also please paste in any relevant debugger info

Answer (score 3):

```
String temp = metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
```

You are doing IPC and disk I/O on the main application thread in every `getView()` call. Do not do this. Either fetch this information up front before populating the list or load it asynchronously (the way that Picasso and other image-loading libraries asynchronously load the image for an `ImageView` used in a `ListView` row).

Also, do not catch exceptions without logging them. Add a `Log.e()` statement or something to your `catch (Exception e)` block.

Comment: Thanks fo answering!

Comment: Just for the testing point of purpose, I removed this line of code and replaced with a dummy code but it is still lagging. It seems that this is not the reason behind this. What should I do now?

Comment: @coderahul1994: Get rid of everything related to `MediaMetadataRetriever` from your `getView()` method. It is possible the slow part is the `setDataSource()` call instead of the `extractMetadata()` call.